# Undefined reference to 'qcos_' and '_g95_qcos_r16' with quad precision in G95

Tags: fortran, precision, g95

I tried to make quad precision on FORTRAN[real(kind=16)], but I keep getting error

```
C:\User\User\AppData\Local\Temp/ccUMY6b.0:forcefunction.f95:(.text+0x437):
undefined reference to 'qcos_'
```

I tried to change `qcos` to `cos` but,

```
C:\User\User\AppData\Local\Temp/ccM5CBUM.0:forcefunction.f95:(.text+0x2fd1):
undefined reference to '_g95_qcos_r16'
```

Same problem for `sin`, `abs`, `acos`, `asin`, `sqrt`

Comment: Can you show how you are defining the variables, and how you are calling `cos`?

Comment: What compiler are you using, and on what platform?

Comment: The 2nd error message suggests that the compiler is g95.

Comment: looks like you need gfortran 4.6+..http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran#What.27s_new_in_gfortran.3F. FWIW v4.2 gives a clear error message that kind=16 is unsupported

Comment: This is g95, not gfortran.

Comment: i was sugesting what compiler he could use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kind=16` is not necessarily quad precision.   kind values are not defined by the language standard and are not portable across compilers.  Sixteen may not be the kind value for quad precision on your compiler.

Not all compilers support quad precision on all architectures.   You can check by printing the following values:

```
selected_real_kind (14)
selected_real_kind (17)
selected_real_kind (32)
```

The first requests double-precision, the next an intermediate precision (10 bytes) that is available sometimes on Intel processors, and the last quad.   If the compiler doesn't support the requested number of decimal digits, the `selected_real_kind` function will return `-1`.

Comment: Given the name of the undefined reference, it is pretty clear that in this case the compiler did recognize kind=16 as quad precision. So what we have here is a linking issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm your problem on my system with g95 4.0.3.

According to this thread http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Fortran/comp.lang.fortran/2009-02/msg00668.html the intrinsic functions are not implemented for quad precision yet. Therefore, you have to change the compiler, or use double precision only.